# Initializer for conditional binding error while trying to build Login

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, runtime-error, social-networking

I am trying to finish my login page for a social media app and I have one error which I can't seem to figure out.

Here is the full code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseDatabase
import SwiftKeychainWrapper

class UserVC: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, 
UINavigationControllerDelegate

{

@IBOutlet weak var userImagePicker: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var CompleteSignInBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
var userUid: String!
var emailField: String!
var passwordField: String!
var imagePicker : UIImagePickerController!
var imageSelected = false
var username: String!


override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
imagePicker.delegate = self
imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
}

func keychain(){
    KeychainWrapper.standard.set(userUid, forKey: "uid")
}
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        userImagePicker.setImage(image,for:.normal)
        imageSelected = true
    } else {
        print("Image was not selected")
    }
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func setUpUser(img: String ){
    let userData = [

        "username": username!,
        "userImg": img
    ]
    keychain()
    let setLocation = Database.database().reference().child(userUid)
    setLocation.setValue(userData)
}


func uploadImg() {

    if usernameField.text == nil {
        print("Please choose a username")
        CompleteSignInBtn.isEnabled = false
    } else {
        username = usernameField.text
        CompleteSignInBtn.isEnabled = true
    }

        guard let img = userImagePicker.image, imageSelected == true else {

        print("image must be selected")

        return
    }


    if let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.2){
        let imgUid = NSUUID().uuidString
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "img/jpeg"

        Storage().reference().child(imgUid).put(imgData, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
            if error =! nil {
                print("Did not upload")
            } else{
                print("Uploaded")
                let downloadURl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                if let url = downloadURl {
                    self.setUpUser(img: url)
                }
            }
        }

    }
  }



@IBAction func completeAccount(_ sender: Any){
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailField, password: passwordField, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error\(error)")
        } else {
            if let user = user {
                self.userUid = user.uid
            }
        }
        self.uploadImg() 
    })
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}


@IBAction func seletedImagePicker(_ sender: Any){
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func cancel(_ sender: AnyObject){
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The code which is causing the error mentioned in the title is this:

```
guard let img = userImagePicker.image, imageSelected == true else {

        print("image must be selected")

        return
    }
```

I have no idea what to do. I read that is has something to do with the fact that userimagePicker.image might not be optional, but in a guide I am following it works.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: [Edit] your question with the complete and exact error.

Comment: i guess you are trying to guard let non optional value . You are already using ! with variables means you have a variable  which is not optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared `userImagePicker` as `UIButton` and `UIButton` has no property called `image`. You should use [`currentImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623998-currentimage)

```
guard let img = userImagePicker.currentImage, imageSelected == true else {
   print("image must be selected")
   return
}
```

Comment: `imageSelected == true` == true is redundant

Comment: @LeoDabus, I see, but I didn't wrote it, I just edited the part that was wrong.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it.

Comment: @user8480321 So yo can accept the answer by clicking the gray tick on the left side.